# DMU11 IMU data straight from port with Python

Tags: serial, imu, python

This is my first python project away from learning through textbook exercises.
I have no other experience coding so sorry that the formatting is likely horrendous.

I'm using [DMU11](https://www.siliconsensing.com/media/30957/dmu11-00-0100-132-rev5.pdf) form Silicon Sensing and want a python program to be able to read the data from it, plot it and save it to a file. I'm currently stuck at the first stage and can't figure out how to get the data to stream using readline.

Also, any help/ comments on the other parts (and/ or better formatting) would also be greatly appreciated!!

Here is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pyreadline as readline

import serial
import time
import sys
import csv

import struct #used to read big-endian format from a file

ser = serial.Serial(port = "COM5",
                           baudrate=460800,
                           bytesize=8,
                           timeout=2,
                           stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO
                           )

print(ser)
    #Gives this: Serial<id=0x3eedd90,open=True>
    #           (port='COM7', baudrate=460800, bytesize=8, parity='N',
    #           stopbits=2, timeout=2, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False,
    #           dsrdtr=False)

    #count = 0

pin_high = "1C13\n"
ser.write(pin_high.encode())
#ser = ser.readline()

#h=2bytes l=4bytes
''' IMU MESSAGE OUTPUT ORDER
Record Number
Time Stamp
Header [2bytes hexID: 0x55AA integer]
Message Count [2bytes 0-65535 integer]
Axis X Rate (°/s) [4bytes hexID: 0x00  SGL]
Axis X Accelerometer Y (g) [4bytes hexID: 0x02  SGL]
Axis X Accelerometer X (g) [4bytes hexID: 0x03  SGL]
Axis X Temperature (°C) [4bytes hexID: 0x06  SGL]
Axis Y Rate (°/s) [4bytes hexID: 0x20  SGL]
Axis Y Accelerometer Y (g) [4bytes hexID: 0x22  SGL]
Axis Y Accelerometer X (g) [4bytes hexID: 0x23  SGL]
Axis Y Temperature (°C) [4bytes hexID: 0x26  SGL]
Axis Z Rate (°/s) [4bytes hexID: 0x40  SGL]
Axis Z Accelerometer Y (g) [4bytes hexID: 0x42  SGL]
Axis Z Accelerometer X (g) [4bytes hexID: 0x43  SGL]
Axis Z Temperature (°C) [4bytes hexID: 0x46  SGL]
IMU Temperature (°C) [4bytes hexID: 0x60  SGL]
Aux Voltage (V) [4bytes hexID: 0x61  SGL]
System Startup BIT Flags [2bytes hexID: 0xC0  Binary]
System Operation BIT Flags [2bytes hexID: 0xC1  Binary]
Item Error Indication Flags 1 - 16 [2bytes hexID: 0xC2  Binary]
Checksum [2bytes 0-65535 integer]
'''

#header, count,
#x_rate, x_acc_y, x_acc_x, x_temp,
#y_rate, y_acc_y, y_acc_x, y_temp,
#z_rate, z_acc_y, z_acc_x, z_temp,
#IMU_temp, AUX_V, StartUp_BIT, Opp_BIT, Error_BIT, checksum = struct.unpack(">hhllllllllllllllhhhh", s)

while True:
    try:
        ser_bytes = ser.readline()
        decoded_bytes = float(ser_bytes[0:len(ser_bytes)-2].decode("utf-8"))
        print(decoded_bytes)
    except:
        print("Keyboard Interrupt")
        break

'''

# Read and record the data
data =[]                       # empty list to store the data
for i in range(50):
    b = ser.readline()         # read a byte string
    string_n = b.decode()  # decode byte string into Unicode  
    string = string_n.rstrip() # remove \n and \r
    flt = float(string)        # convert string to float
    print(flt)
    data.append(flt)           # add to the end of data list
    time.sleep(0.1)            # wait (sleep) 0.1 seconds

ser.close()

for line in data:
    print(line)
'''
#break
    
if ser.isOpen():
    ser.close()
ser.open()
ser.isOpen()

ser.read()
#Gives the output: b'\t'


print(ser.read(64))

dataPacket = ser.readline() #reply
dataPacket=str(dataPacket,'utf-16')
print(dataPacket)

# Gives the output: b'\x1f=B\x16\xa0\x8cB-\x87\x8e@*\xd5\xde\xbf\x1fg\xbfDz,mB\x18bsB\x18)\xac@SO\xad<\xa0\x8f\x82A\x04c\xa4\xbf\x8e\xd6\xcbC\n\xdc\xd2\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x1bU\xaa\xd3M'

#out = ''

# let's wait one second before reading output (let's give device time to answer)
time.sleep(1)
while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
    out += ser.read(40)

if out != '':
    print(">>" + out)


ser.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use readline, because it works with data separated with newline data sequences.

The sensor sends packets of binary data, not lines of text characters.